# Integrate Esri WebMap in MS PowerPlatform

Tags: arcgis-online-webmap, microsoft-flow

We have a requirement for a new enterprise level application that is asking to integrate an Esri WebMap into a MS PowerPlatform app, preferably a Canvas app.

Just looking into possible methodology to accomplish this requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the official documentation there's an example with map control applicable to canvas apps https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/component-framework/sample-controls/map-control and a git repository with code https://github.com/microsoft/PowerApps-Samples/tree/master/component-framework/MapControl.